# Button on being saved in word VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I have this piece of code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Controls.Button salesButton;
    Document vstodoc = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application objApplication = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection objSelection = objApplication.Selection;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range objRange = objSelection.Range;
    salesButton = vstodoc.Controls.AddButton(objRange, 20, 20, "salesButton");
    salesButton.Text = "Calculate Total Sales";
}
```

When I click on the button a button is inserted inside Word document, but when I save it and try to reopen the word document the button is not there anymore.

**Before I save the Word document:**
[image]

**After I save the Word document:**

[image]

Comment: Do you develop a document-level or application-level add-in? Do you save the document as macro-enabled?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev i dont understand 
but its not made as a macro thou

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/certain-buttons-on-bar-not-working-on-microsoft/50eec02b-912f-425e-8ef3-c8eb48e51bbf

Have a look, couldn't hurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution to this problem.

**1**. all dynamically created host controls are disconnected from their events and they lose their data binding functionality. You can add code to your solution to re-create the host controls when the document is reopened [(Dynamic MsControl)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/adding-controls-to-office-documents-at-run-time?view=vs-2019)

**Step 1**
create a word-addsin
[image]

**Step 2**
Add reference to the project for

`Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.v4.0.Utilities.dll`
[image]

**Step 3**
Add a ribbon to the project
[image]

- Now your project should look like this
  [image]

**Step 4**
go to your `ThisAddsIn.cs` file

```
 public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
 
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }
        
        #endregion
    }
```

create a new method in the above class name it `WhenRibionBtnIsClicked()`

```
  private Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Controls.Button button = null;//decalre a global varible
  internal void WhenRibionBtnIsClicked()
  {
    Document vstoDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(this.Application.ActiveDocument);
    Word.Selection selection = this.Application.Selection;
    if (selection != null && selection.Range != null)
    {
      string name ="myBtn";
      Button button = new Button();
      button.Click += new EventHandler(Generatedbtn_Click);
      button = vstoDocument.Controls.AddButton(selection.Range, 100, 30, name);
     
      button.Text = "I am A Generated Button";
      button.Name = name;
     
     /*this part is done so that when the document is closed the button state is saved in the document property*/
      string startPosition = selection.Range.Start.ToString();
      string endPosition = selection.Range.End.ToString();
      //create a custom property to save infornmation needed to recreate the button
    Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties =(DocumentProperties)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties;

//save the start range pos
   if (properties.Cast<DocumentProperty>().Where(c => c.Name == "startPosition").Count() == 0)
    {
      properties.Add("startPosition", false, MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, startPosition);
    }
    else{
          properties["startPosition"].Value = startPosition;
          Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Saved = false; //important somtimes
        }

      //save the End range pos
   if (properties.Cast<DocumentProperty>().Where(c => c.Name == "endPosition").Count() == 0)
   {
     properties.Add("endPosition", false, MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, endPosition);
   }else
       {
         properties["endPosition"].Value = endPosition;
         Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Saved = false; //important somtimes
       }
   // Store Button Info
   if (properties.Cast<DocumentProperty>().Where(c => c.Name == "btnName").Count() == 0)
     {
      properties.Add("btnName", false, MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, name);
     } else
            {
               properties["btnName"].Value = startPosition;
               Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Saved = false; //important somtimes
            }

  if (properties.Cast<DocumentProperty>().Where(c => c.Name == "btnText").Count() == 0)
  {
    properties.Add("btnText", false, MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, "I am A Generated Button");
  }else
      {
        properties["btnText"].Value = "I am A Generated Button";
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Saved = false; //important somtimes                    
      }
   //you can add more custom properties just like how i added start and end strings
    }//end of if selection != null && selection.Range != null

  }//end of WhenRibionBtnIsClicked Method
```

**Step 5**
Create a button click event for the button that has been generated in the word file

```
 void Generatedbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("I have Been Clicked :-O");
 }
```

**Step 6**
and now in the `Ribbon.cs` file
get the click event of the button created in the ribbon and point it to the above created class

```
  private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.WhenRibionBtnIsClicked();
        }
```

so now when you run it you should be able to see the following:
[image]

however the problem you will face after this is when you save the document this things are removed the so what you must do is re-create this buttons when the word starts and use the properties you have stored to get the button state or other info about the button

**Step 7**
go to the function `ThisAddIn_Startup`

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  Word.Application wb;
  wb = this.Application;
  if (wb.Documents.Count > 0)
   {
      String queryResult_StartPosition = String.Empty;
      String queryResult_EndPosition = String.Empty;
      String queryResult_btnName = String.Empty;
      String queryResult_btnText = String.Empty;
      Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties = (DocumentProperties)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties;

     //get doc info about start pos
     if (properties.Cast<DocumentProperty>().Where(c => c.Name == "startPosition").Count() > 0)
    {
        queryResult_StartPosition = properties["startPosition"].Value;
    }
    else
       {
         queryResult_StartPosition = String.Empty;
       }
       //get doc info about end pos
                
    if (properties.Cast<DocumentProperty>().Where(c => c.Name == "endPosition").Count() > 0)
  {
    queryResult_EndPosition = properties["endPosition"].Value;
  }
   else
       {
         queryResult_EndPosition = String.Empty;
       }
   //get info about btn name
    if (properties.Cast<DocumentProperty>().Where(c => c.Name == "btnName").Count() > 0)
     {
       queryResult_btnName = properties["btnName"].Value;
     }
      else
         {
           queryResult_btnName = String.Empty;
         }
      //get info about btn text
 if (properties.Cast<DocumentProperty>().Where(c => c.Name == "issue_title").Count() > 0)
 {
   queryResult_btnText = properties["btnText"].Value;
 }
   else
   {
     queryResult_btnText = String.Empty;
   }

 Document vstoDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(this.Application.ActiveDocument);
 Word.Range rng = vstoDocument.Range(queryResult_StartPosition, queryResult_EndPosition); 
 Word.Selection selection = this.Application.Selection;
 if (selection != null && rng != null)
 {
   Button button = new Button();
   button.Click += new EventHandler(Generatedbtn_Click);
   button = vstoDocument.Controls.AddButton(rng, 100, 30, queryResult_btnName);
   button.Text = queryResult_btnText;
 }
}//end of wb.Documents
 
}//end of ThisAddIn_Startup
```

the above code should be able to get all your info from the custom property that you made and re-create the button.
if for some reason when you start the document and the `adds-in` tab does not show up in word that means there is an error in your `ThisAddIn_Startup` function
-to debug try putting everything in `ThisAddIn_Startup` function into a separate button then test and see the error code.
Please Note: you can basicaly do everything you would do in a normal C# form (opening forms closing forms,reading text files, and etc)

i have provided a sample in github with a debug button you can check

[Persist Dynamic Control](https://github.com/kunz398/word-integration-with-VSTO)